# Saving and Loading a Class Instance

Tags: python, persistence, pickle, savestate

I have a class that creates a new character object.

```
class Character():
    def __init__(self):
    self.name = None
    self.hp = None
    self.mp = None


class Race(Character):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.race = None
```

That is located in a module called char. So I have my code for creating a new game.

```
    elif command == "new game":
        name_game = input('Name your game: ')

        cur_save=open('saves/' + name_game + '.p', 'wb')
        player = char.Character()
        player_name = input('Name your character: ')
        player.name = player_name
        player_race = input('What is your race? ')
        player.race = player_race
        pickle.dump(player, cur_save, -1)
        cur_save.close()
```

Now I want to start the game and load the players name and race that were entered. But the following just sets player to undefined.

```
    cur_save=open('saves/' + name_game + '.p', 'rb')
    player = pickle.load(cur_save)
```

I want it to set the player.name to the saved value and same with player.race.
Is there something else I should be using like a database sort of thing (MySQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I made a quick test and have no problems:

```
import pickle
class Character():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.hp = None
        self.mp = None


class Race(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.race = None

name_game = input('Name your game: ')

cur_save=open('saves/' + name_game + '.p', 'wb')
player = Character()
player_name = input('Name your character: ')
player.name = player_name
player_race = input('What is your race? ')
player.race = player_race
pickle.dump(player, cur_save, -1)
cur_save.close()

cur_save=open('saves/' + name_game + '.p', 'rb')
player = pickle.load(cur_save)
print(player.name)
```

and what I get is:

```
%run temp.py
Name your game: test
Name your character: Brian
What is your race? human
Brian
```

Sometimes, I've seen things fail with pickle if the definition of your class has changed, or even if you redefine the class (maybe by running a bit of code again). For example, lets say I run the first bit of code as above, and then run

```
class Character():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.hp = None
        self.mp = None
```

again, essentially redefining Character. Then you can get unintuitive behavior:

```
In [17]: player.__class__
Out[17]: __main__.Character
In [18]: player.__class__ == Character
Out[18]: False

In [20]: player2 = Character()
In [21]: player2.__class__
Out[21]: __main__.Character
In [22]: player2.__class__ == Character
Out[22]: True
```

So you might want to make sure something like that isn't happening. Usually it doesn't matter, but if variable names change or something, it can throw you off.

Comment: Also, just a pointer on style:  instead of opening and closing the file, you can use with:  "with open(filename) as f: " which will automatically close the file when you leave the context. See http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/ for an example.

Comment: Yes I believe that is what is happening. I restart the program and when I do it imports my class Character() module so when I go to load the save.p file and assign the values to player. It says player is not defined. How can I make this sort of thing work? I want the players stats to be updated throughout the game and saved on exit, but able to be reloaded later on. And thank you sheridp I will change that :)

Comment: I got it to work, it was an error on my end. Thank you for your help